# регулярные выражения не работает знак вопроса

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не работает такое выражение:

```
~сда[мюе][тм]?(ся)?~iUu
```

Например из строки "Сдается ПСН" выбирает только "Сдае".
Путем экспериментов понял, что не работает знак вопроса в регулярке как с [] так и с (). Хотя по документации все должно работать...
Почему не пойму. Где в консерватории подкрутить?

Comment: Какой диалект регулярок используете (платформа, ЯП)? В .NET захватывается слово "Сдается" нормально

Comment: php 5.5 ,5.6. А также пробовал в https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html и https://regex101.com

Comment: А зачем вы большую U в флагах поставили ? С ней она старается захватить как можно меньше и все, что под вопросом решает проигнорировать, так как после искать больше нечего. Без U все отлично https://regex101.com/r/gGTeKC/1

Comment: Мда. Заклинило. не попробовал. В принципе мне и нужно как можно меньше. Но ведь в слове "Сдается" присутствуют все символы из шаблона. И я думал, минимум что регулярка заберет это все слово целиком. Я дал для примера только часть шаблона, а в нем еще много чего есть, поэтому и U. Спасибо. Буду думать дальше.

Answer (score 4):

Вы указали флаг `U`, он обозначает не жадный режим работы регулярного выражения. В этом режиме *механизм* старается захватывать как можно меньше символов при условии совпадения остальной части выражения. Т.е. для вопросительных знаков он сначала проверяет удастся ли достигнуть цели, то есть получить соответствие если данная группа не захватит ничего. Так как после условий с вопросительными знаками не идет более никаких утверждений, то *механизм* вполне устраивает первая найденная часть. Вот если бы после частей с `?` стояло бы какое нибудь обязательное утверждение (например пробел), то *механизм* не найдя пробела сразу после "Сдае" попробовал бы использовать не обязательные группы и был бы вынужден их использовать, что привело бы к совпадению "Сдается ".

Без модификатора `U` регулярка, находясь в "жадном" редиме захватывает все, что может захватить. [Пример](https://regex101.com/r/gGTeKC/1).

Поэтому обычно лучше не использовать глобальный модификатор уменьшения жадности, а использовать локальные модификаторы в тех местах, где они действительно необходимы. Локальный модификатор в данном случае - это еще один знак вопроса. Например, выражение `/сда[мюе][тм]?(ся)??/` захватит часть "Сдает", так как `[тм]` хоть и не обязательно, но захватывается при первой возможности, а вот `(ся)` ищется только в том случае, если без него действительно не обойтись для продолжения.

Comment: Конечно поиск всего слова "Сдается" не сильно принципиален, но в некоторых случаях это необходимо, чтобы избежать неоднозначности определения слова. Например: сдает металлолом, и сдает экзамены и сдает помещение. В этом случае и в контексте анализа текста "сдается" будет практически однозначно определять сдачу помещения.

Comment: @sergvm "Услуги репититора. У наших учащихся отлично сдаются экзамены". Боюсь одним словом не обойтись. Все равно надо смотреть контекст. Что касается одного слова, то я пока не вижу в задаче необходимости уменьшения жадности.

Comment: Я бы подчеркнул **лучше не использовать глобальный модификатор уменьшения жадности**. От этого всё время возникают проблемы.

Comment: В общем и целом все понятно. Есть куда работать:) Спасибо.